# back button don't get change color in navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Sorry for bad english:-(
Here i am using xcode 5 and ios7, Can dnt change color in back button when get after pushviewcontroller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        ListViewController *viewList = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@“ListViewController” bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewList animated:YES];
}
```

User presses a cell then ListViewController will appear. In Navigation bar, Right bar button appeared pink color. but did not get change color in back bar button. Please see screen shoot i have attached link below.

[image]

Can we change color back button in navigation bar?. Or Should add image in back button?

Comment: This color is ios7 default color, you should replace it with image only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        ListViewController *viewList = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@“ListViewController” bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor readcolor]; //set color as you want…..
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewList animated:YES];
}
```

Try it... Happy code :-)

Answer (score 6):

For change all `UIBarButtonItems` color in your app, set the `tintColor` property on the application's window in the AppDelegate. such like,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // or set color as you want.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can also set this in the storyboard as well.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a `backBarButtonItem`'s colour but you can change its tint. Try adding the following to your App Delegate:
`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColour:pinkColour]`

Be careful, this will tint **ALL** of your bar buttons pink.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for customized back button

```
UIView *backBtnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)];
backBtnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIButton *backBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 57, 30)];
[backBtnView addSubview:backBtn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backBtnView];
```